# SublimeREPL scala error

Tags: scala, runtime-error, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I installed SublimeREPL, but every time I try to launch the REPL, I get a dialog showing the error "OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')".

I have Scala 2.10 installed using MacPorts.

I am running OS X Lion (10.8.3).

Is there some special configuration I need to tell SublimeREPL where to find the Scala executable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Sublime Text installation directory (it will likely be under `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2`), there's a configuration file:

`./Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Scala/Main.sublime-menu`

The path to scala and its invocation are defined by:

```
"cmd": {"linux": ["scala"],
        "osx": ["scala"],
        "windows": ["scala.bat", "-i"]
       },
...
"extend_env": {"osx": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"},
               "linux": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/local/bin"},
               "windows": {"EMACS": "1"}
},
```

Comment: That worked. I changed the executable name to `scala-2.10` and the path to `/opt/local/bin`.