# SublimeREPL scala error... Same error, but existing solution does not fix the issue

Tags: linux, scala, sublimetext2, sbt, sublimerepl

While running `SublimeREPL: SBT for opened folder`, I have the exact same problem as in [The similar question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641416/sublimerepl-scala-error) (`OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')`).

Unofrtunately, the solution provided there did not help much.

Would anybody be kind enough to give some clues as to what might still be wrong here?

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04.

My `Main.sublime-menu` config is as follows:

```
[
 {
    "id": "tools",
    "children":
    [{
        "caption": "SublimeREPL",
        "mnemonic": "r",
        "id": "SublimeREPL",
        "children":
        [
            {"caption": "Scala",
            "id": "Scala",

             "children":[
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "scala REPL",
                 "id": "repl_scala",
                 "mnemonic": "s",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "scala",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["scala"],
                            "osx": ["scala"],
                            "windows": ["scala.bat", "-i"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                    "extend_env": {"osx": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/home/helluin/apps/sbt/bin"},
                                   "linux": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/home/helluin/apps/sbt/bin/"},
                                   "windows": {"EMACS": "1"}},
                    "suppress_echo": false, 
                    "syntax": "Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage"
                    }
                },
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "SBT for opened folder",
                 "id": "repl_sbt",
                 "mnemonic": "b",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "external_id": "scala",
                    "cmd": {"linux": ["sbt"],
                            "osx": ["sbt"],
                            "windows": ["sbt"]},
                    "soft_quit": "\nexit\n",
                    "cwd": "$folder",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                    "extend_env": {"osx": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/bin"},
                                   "linux": {"EMACS": "1", "PATH": "{PATH}:/usr/bin"},
                                   "windows": {"EMACS": "1"}},
                    "suppress_echo": false, 
                    "syntax": "Packages/Scala/Scala.tmLanguage"
                    }
                } 
            ]}
        ]
    }]
  }
]
```

Also, the `scala` and `sbt` system paths are defined thusly

```
λ →  which scala
/usr/bin/scala
λ →  which sbt
/home/helluin/apps/sbt/bin/sbt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your paths mixed up. The `"caption": "scala REPL"` menu item has `scala` as its command, but the extended `PATH` is `/home/helluin/apps/sbt/bin`. The `"caption": "SBT for opened folder"` item has `sbt` as its command, yet the extended `PATH` is `/usr/bin`. You should switch them.

Alternatively, for the Scala REPL, make the first line of the command:

```
"cmd": {"linux": ["/usr/bin/scala"],
```

(although `/usr/bin` should already be in the system `PATH`). For the `sbt` REPL, make the first line of the command:

```
"cmd": {"linux": ["/home/helluin/apps/sbt/bin/sbt"],
```

and then you don't need to worry about extending that particular environment variable.